# Installing a new font in Tesseract on windows

Tags: windows, ocr, tesseract

I have just installed the most recent version of Tesseract on Windows 10 but I find it does not work with seanchló, or old Irish script. Fortunately someone has done something to address that, here:

https://github.com/kscanne/tesseract-gle-uncial

But it seems I need a .traineddata file, which doesn't appear to be in that fairly old repository. Does anyone know how I might be able to extract or generate this file and use it to read some 1910s-era documents?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this release by one of the contributors of the repository you linked. It seems to be a fork of the repo and contains the `gle_uncial.traineddata` file.

[jimregan/tesseract-gle-uncial/releases](https://github.com/jimregan/tesseract-gle-uncial/releases/tag/v0.1beta3)

To use it just copy it to where ever your `tessdata` folder is and pass it as a `-l` argument to Tesseract OCR.